# Creating session in razor

Tags: c#, razor, session-variables

I have been trying the following code to create a session

`@{string Session.UserId = "32";}`

No matter what I change it shows an error (right now "expected ;"). What is the right way to create a session variable? I dont mind creating a string or an int or a boolean. I am basically trying an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
@{
  Session["UserId"] = "32";
}
```

Comment: worked thanks. 
now i am trying `Session["Usercheck"] = (a==32)`
which will directly set the value of Session["Usercheck"] to true or false without 

`if (a==32){
    Session["Usercheck"] = true
}`
`else {
    Session["Usercheck"] = false
}